# How to set default debugger at project level in VSCode

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-debugger

In VS Code when I click `Run > Start Debugging (F5)` it asks for the debugger with a list, or it starts debugging with the debugger related to open file. I want to tell VSCode to always debug with a specific debugger no matter what file is open, Is this possible?

[image]

I tried adding some code in the following file, but it did not work, saying those configuration doesn't exist. What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: @starball it's close, but the question & purpose are different so I would like to keep these questions if SO doesn't mind a question variation for seeker's pov.

Comment: I can see where you're coming from. just trying to apply interpretation of [/help/duplicates](/help/duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

later I tried and this worked:
created `launch.json` inside `project_folder/.vscode/`

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "program": "lib/main.dart"
        }
    ]
}
```